# The kth great number

Tags: c++, data-structures

What kind of data structure can I use to solve this problem:

If input contains:

- +1 - Insert element with value Ki
- 0 - Find and print Kth largest element
- -1 - Delete element with value Ki

Example input:

```
8
+1 5
+1 3
+1 7
0 2
-1 3
0 1
+1 10
0 3
```

And output:

```
5
7
5
```

Comment: A [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)?

Comment: You can use any container, honestly. Which container is *best* is up for debate.

Comment: A container that is kept sorted. Add/remove elements always maintaining sorted order (largest to smallest). Finding the Kth largest becomes trivial: access element at index K.

Comment: `std::set` is probably the easiest. Just sort from bigger to smaller. I don't think performance is really the issue here so go for easy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Data structure: *self-balancing BST* (e.g. red-black tree)

Container in c++: *set*

Time complexities:

- Insertion: `O(log(n))`
- Deletion: `O(log(n))`
- K-th order statistic: `O(n)`

Comment: There is no good reason why K-th element need be that slow in a self-balancing BST in general.  `std::set` makes it that slow, true, but...

Comment: @Yakk Agree. In plain RBT, you can't find K-th element faster than `O(n)` cause you have to traverse the tree. If BST is modified a bit; like with adding counters of nodes in the left sub-tree and right sub-tree for each node, then it can be `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use some form of binary search tree:
`std::set` is accessed by key and looks like and exact fit for your needs. 
`std::map` is an associative container, usually implemented as red-black tree.

In your case I'd go with `std::set`:

```
//getting the n-th element in set
auto it = std::next(myset.begin(), n);
```

For the sake of completeness I should also mention std::vector + std::sort, which is algorithmically less effective, but if you do not have huge data sets it would be more performant due to data locality (vector lays contained objects in a sequential manner in a preallocated chunk of memory).

Comment: `std::set`isn't accessed by index. it is accessed by key. Not that it matters that much, you can iterate over it in O(K) time so..

Comment: Was thinking of brute-force vector + sorting solution while typing the set piece :) Fixed it.

Comment: Actually i think the vector solution is better in a lot of use cases. data-locality beats this minor increase in algorithmic complexity everyday of the week. And twice on sundays.

Comment: `std::set` is not an exact fit.  There is no reason for an O(n) cost to find the kth key, other than the inexactness of the fit of `std::set`.  A naive skip-list would support every operation in O(lg n) expected time, for example, as would a BST with counts at each node.  `std` lacks both.